# Microsoft Graph API add scp or roles claim

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

This is how I get the access token with PHP microsoft/graph lib

```
$token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$data = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',

];

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $token_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response_data = json_decode($response, true);
$accessToken = $response_data['access_token'];
```

How can I add scp or roles claim for the access token?

[image: Postman]
[image: App API Permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, client credentials flow only works with permissions of
> **`Application`** type. The error occurred as you are using **Delegated** permissions.

I registered one Azure AD application and added `Sites.Read.All` permission of **Delegated** type:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to list sites, I got **same error** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to add `Sites.Read.All` permission of **Application** type and make sure to grant **admin consent** to it:

[image]

Now, generate the token again using **client credentials** flow after granting consent to above permission.

To check whether the token has permission or not, you can **decode** it by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) site and find **`roles`** claim:

[image]

When I used this token to list sites by running below query again, I got **response** successfully:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

**Response:**

[image]